# Is there any logic to compare two word documents(docx) and catch the missing String, Special chars, space and all the stuff?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm working on two word document comparison manually where i should not miss any Strings, Special chars, space and all the stuff and that document is around 150 pages or more. so its very headache to do comparison. Then I have written small java program to compare two documents but I'm not able to list the missing words.

Using Apche POI Library

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFFooter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHeader;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;

public class ReadDocFile {

    private static XWPFDocument docx;
    // private static String path = "C:\\States wise\\NH\\Assessment
    // 2nd\\test.docx";
    private static ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>(); // refers to first document list
    private static ArrayList<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>(); // refers to second document list
    private static List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphList;
    private static Map<String, String> map = null; 
    private static LinkedHashSet<String> firstMissedArray = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); // refers to first document Linked hash set
    private static LinkedHashSet<String> secondMissedArray = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); // refers to second document Linked hash set

    
    public static void getFilePath(String path) {

        FileInputStream fis;
        try {

            fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            docx = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void get_First_Doc_Data() {

        getFilePath("C:\\States wise\\NH\\Assessment 2nd\\test.docx");

        paragraphList = docx.getParagraphs();

        System.out.println("******************** first list Starts here  ******************** ");
        System.out.println();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphList.size() - 1; i++) {

            firstList.add(paragraphList.get(i).getText().toString());

            System.out.println(firstList.get(i).toString());

        }

        System.out.println("*********** first list Ends here ********************");

    }

    public static void get_Second_Doc_Data() {

        getFilePath("C:\\States wise\\NH\\Assessment 2nd\\test1.docx");

        paragraphList = docx.getParagraphs();

        System.out.println("******************** Second list Starts here  ******************** ");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphList.size() - 1; i++) {

            secondList.add(paragraphList.get(i).getText().toString());

            System.out.println(secondList.get(i).toString());

        }

        System.out.println("*********** Second list Ends here ********************");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        get_First_Doc_Data();

        get_Second_Doc_Data();

        //System.out.println("First Para: " + firstList.contains(secondList));

        compare();

        compare_Two_List();

        }

    private static void compare() {
        String firstMiss = null;
        //String secondMiss = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < firstList.size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < secondList.size(); j++) {

                if (!firstList.get(i).toString().equals(secondList.get(i).toString())) {

                    firstMiss = firstList.get(i).toString();

                    //secondMiss = secondList.get(i).toString();

                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                }
            }

            firstMissedArray.add(firstMiss);
            //secondMissedArray.add(secondMiss);

            // System.out.println(missedArray.get(i).toString());

        }

    }

    private static void compare_Two_List() {

        int num = 0;
        map.clear();

        Iterator<String> first = firstMissedArray.iterator();
        //Iterator<String> second = secondMissedArray.iterator();

        while (first.hasNext()) {
            
            map.put(""+num, first.next());
            
            num++;
            
        }

        System.out.println(firstMissedArray.size());

        Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
            // it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken liberty to modify your code to arrive at the solution for your problem. Please go through this.
This should pretty much solve your problem - put SYSO statements wherever you think is necessary and tweak the flow of the program to achieve desired checks as per you requirement. In my hurry, I may not have made use of coding standards of using try catch block for error handling and handling the negative scenarios, so please take care of that when implementing it live.

In case if the documents are not .DOCX but .PDF make use of the Apache PDFBox api.

Here is the Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;

public class Comapre_Docs {
    private static final String FIRST_DOC_PATH = "E:\\Workspace_Luna\\assignments\\Expected.docx";
    private static final String SECOND_DOC_PATH = "E:\\Workspace_Luna\\assignments\\Actual.docx";
    private static XWPFDocument docx;
    private static List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphList;
    private static ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ArrayList<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void get_Doc_Data(String filePath, ArrayList listName)
            throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        docx = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        paragraphList = docx.getParagraphs();

        for (int i = 0; i <= paragraphList.size() - 1; i++) {
            listName.add(paragraphList.get(i).getText().toString());
        }
        fis.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        get_Doc_Data(FIRST_DOC_PATH, firstList);
        get_Doc_Data(SECOND_DOC_PATH, secondList);
        compare(firstList, secondList);
    }

    private static void compare(ArrayList<String> firstList_1,
            ArrayList<String> secondList_1) {
        simpleCheck(firstList_1, secondList_1);
        int size = firstList_1.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            paragraphCheck(firstList_1.get(i).toString().split(" "),
                    secondList_1.get(i).toString().split(" "), i);
        }
    }

    private static void paragraphCheck(String[] firstParaArray,
            String[] secondParaArray, int paraNumber) {
        System.out
                .println("=============================================================");
        System.out.println("Paragraph No." + (paraNumber + 1) + ": Started");
        if (firstParaArray.length != secondParaArray.length) {
            System.out.println("There is mismatch of "
                    + Math.abs(firstParaArray.length - secondParaArray.length)
                    + " words in this paragraph");
        }
        TreeMap<String, Integer> firstDocPara = getOccurence(firstParaArray);
        TreeMap<String, Integer> secondDocPara = getOccurence(secondParaArray);
        ArrayList<String> keyData = new ArrayList<String>(firstDocPara.keySet());
        for (int i = 0; i < keyData.size(); i++) {
            if (firstDocPara.get(keyData.get(i)) != secondDocPara.get(keyData
                    .get(i))) {
                System.out
                        .println("The following word is missing in actual document : "
                                + keyData.get(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Paragraph No." + (paraNumber + 1) + ": Done");
        System.out
                .println("=============================================================");
    }

    private static TreeMap<String, Integer> getOccurence(String[] paraArray) {
        TreeMap<String, Integer> paragraphStringCountHolder = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        paragraphStringCountHolder.clear();
        for (String a : paraArray) {
            int count = 1;
            if (paragraphStringCountHolder.containsKey(a)) {
                count = paragraphStringCountHolder.get(a) + 1;
                paragraphStringCountHolder.put(a, count);
            } else {
                paragraphStringCountHolder.put(a, count);
            }
        }
        return paragraphStringCountHolder;
    }

    private static boolean simpleCheck(ArrayList<String> firstList,
            ArrayList<String> secondList) {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (firstList.size() > secondList.size()) {
            System.out
                    .println("There are more paragraph in Expected document than in Actual document");
        } else if (firstList.size() < secondList.size()) {
            System.out
                    .println("There are more paragraph in Actual document than in Expected document");
        } else if (firstList.size() == secondList.size()) {
            System.out.println("The paragraph count in both documents match");
            flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    }

}
```